# How do I stop my three async API function calls from running out of order since they are dependent on each other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three API calls I need to make in my Chart.js file.

As you can see fetchTZ is dependent on FetchCoordinates, and fetchData is dependent on both TimeZone and Coordinates to not be null.

Right now everything is running randomly, so most of the time that ends with fetchData resulting in an error.
I need the order to always be FetchCoordinate... then FetchTZ... then FetchData

**Gets coordinates from city**

```
 async function fetchCoordinate(city) {
    try {
      const res = await fetchCoordinates(city);
      if (!res) {
        console.log(("FetchCoordinates failed"));
        return;
      }
      let center = res.features[0].center;
      setLongitude(center[0]);
      setLatitude(center[1]);
   
      return center; // Return the center coordinates
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error if needed
      console.error('Error fetching coordinates:', error);
      throw error; // Re-throw the error to be caught in the promise chain
    }
```

** Fetches TimeZone from Coordinates **

```
  async function fetchTZ(center) {
    try {
      if (center) {
        const res = await fetchTimeZone(center[1], center[0]);
        if (!res) {
          console.log(("FetchTZ failed"));
          return;
        } else {
          const zone = res[0].timezone.name;
          setTimeZone(zone);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error if needed
      console.error('Error fetching TZ:', error);
    }
  }
```

/// Fetches Astrology Chart

```
const fetchData = async () => {
          const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://astrologer.p.rapidapi.com/api/v3/birth-chart',
            headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json',
              'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'a21b096736msh14ea0bd4386759fp11f46cjsn735c8552bfc3',
              'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'astrologer.p.rapidapi.com'
            },
            data: {
              name: name,
              year: year,
              month: month,
              day: day,
              hour: hour,
              minute: minute,
              longitude: longitude,
              latitude: latitude,
              city: city,
              timezone: timeZone,
              language: 'IT'
            }
          };
        
          try {
            const response = await axios.request(options);
          
            setChart(response.data);
            console.log(chart);
            console.log('Fetch chart ran');
            jupiter = response.data.jupiter;
            pluto =  '';
            neptune = '';
            uruanus = '';
            saturn = '';
            mars = '';
            moon = '';
            sun = '';
            mercury = '';
            venus = '';
  
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
```

I tried writing promises but I seem to not be understanding how to do it.

Comment: You haven't shown the code where you are actually calling the functions

Comment: As Bergi said, add to your question the code where you call fetchCoordinate(city) then fetchTZ(center).